# UIscrollView image from web in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to make a gallery with UIScrollview like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift).

In case, I want to get the images from web, but with this code my VC is very slow to load

```
var pageImage: [UIImage] = []   
 for d in image {
                    var imgUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://images.com/\(d.thumbnail)")!

                    var imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgUrl)
                    pageImage.append(UIImage(data: imgData!)!)


               }
```

How to make my VC load faster?

Answer (score 0):

Only load the images when you actually need them. Use the scroll view delegate to find out when an image is about to appear on screen.

You should also not fetch the images on the UIThread which will make the app feel unresponsive. I would recommend using a 3rd party lib for loading and displaying the images such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage%20SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking+UIImageView](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score -1):

as eric said you are loading imae on main thread you can set image in swift with url like imageView.setImageWithURL

or you can load image with background thread